# Is there any difference between "the rise of the moon" and "the rising of the moon"?

Tags: nouns

I would like to know how these two are different, "the rise of the moon" and "the rising of the moon", or if any of them is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Using the participle emphasizes the verbal concept - the movement. Using the noun emphasizes the object - the moon itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **both are acceptable**.

Long answer:

Although different dictionaries define **rising** only as **uprising** and as **about to become** ([CALD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rising), [LDOCE Online](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/rising), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rising)), which might at first indicate "traditional... ish" sort of situation, ODO nevertheless [defines it](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rising) as

> 1 Going up, increasing, or sloping upward.
>
> *‘the rising temperature’*

which is logical.

Ngram Viewer also rises against, so to say, CALD, LDOCE, M-W, etc. and [shows prevailation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rise+of+the+moon%2Crising+of+the+moon&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crise%20of%20the%20moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brise%20of%20the%20moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRise%20of%20the%20Moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brise%20of%20the%20Moon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crising%20of%20the%20moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brising%20of%20the%20moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRising%20of%20the%20Moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brising%20of%20the%20Moon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRISING%20OF%20THE%20MOON%3B%2Cc0) of **"rising..."** over **"rise..."**:
[image: ngram]

Corpus of Contemporary American English ([COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)) also agrees with Ngram Viewer and indicates, again, prevailation of **"rising..."** over **"rise..."** with a result of **12 over 1**:
[image: coca-rising]
[image: coca-rise]

With all this data, it is possible to conclude that **both are acceptable**.

P.S. Probably it depends on how you think about it. If we are saying something like

> The **rising** of the Moon

we are probably thinking about **a continuous process**, whereas if we are talking about

> The **rise** of the Moon

we are probably meaning an event which starts somewhere in time and ends somewhere in time shortly after. But this is entirely my opinion which can be wrong. All we need to know is that **both "rising..." and "rise..." are acceptable.**

Comment: Moonrise is also a noun for the event.

Comment: Nevertheless, there is an Irish song called 'The Rising of the Moon', and the phrase 'the rising of the sun' also occurs in several contexts.

Comment: I agree. Seems like I was incorrect, because [Ngram also shows prevailation](https://imgur.com/y5vx0ZF) of **rising** over **rise**. Probably it depends on how the process is thought of. If one emphasises that the process is continuous, then **rising** is used. If the process is meant as a time point, then **rise** is used.

Comment: Done. Answer edited.